When I use C++ to load the custom TensorRT plugin of mmdploy, “segmentation error occurs“”

My env：

Ubuntu 20.04
CUDA 11.3
tensorRT 8.5.1.7
g++ 9.4


I can be sure that there is no problem with my libmmdeploy_tensorrt_ops.so, because I have loaded it in Python in the same environment and no memory error has occurred. Infer works perfectly.
Below is the code of my C++ main program, which will have a segmentation fault after entering nvinfer1::IExecutionContext* context = engine->createExecutionContext();
    std::string pluginLibraryPath = "mylibpath/libmmdeploy_tensorrt_ops.so";
    std::string engineFilePath = "myenginepath/cascade-rcnn/end2end.engine";
    std::string imagePath = "myimagepath/1544580881017339287.jpg";

    // Load the TensorRT engine
    nvinfer1::IRuntime* runtime = nvinfer1::createInferRuntime(gLogger);
    assert(runtime != nullptr);
    if (!runtime) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create runtime" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    void* plugin_handle = dlopen(pluginLibraryPath.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!plugin_handle) {
        std::cerr << "load plugin fail: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    
    nvinfer1::IPluginRegistry* pluginRegistry = getPluginRegistry();
    if (!pluginRegistry) {
        std::cerr << "regist plugin fail" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Load engine
    char *trtModelStream{ nullptr };
    size_t size{ 0 };

    std::ifstream engineFile(engineFilePath, std::ios::binary);
    if (engineFile.good()) {
        engineFile.seekg(0, engineFile.end);
        size = engineFile.tellg();
        engineFile.seekg(0, engineFile.beg);
        trtModelStream = new char[size];
        assert(trtModelStream);
        engineFile.read(trtModelStream, size);
        engineFile.close();
    }

    nvinfer1::ICudaEngine* engine = runtime->deserializeCudaEngine(trtModelStream, size, nullptr);
    assert(engine != nullptr);


    nvinfer1::IExecutionContext* context = engine->createExecutionContext();
    assert(context != nullptr);

and I print the normal log:
Loaded engine size: 148 MiB
[MemUsageChange] Init cuBLAS/cuBLASLt: CPU +942, GPU +202, now: CPU 1177, GPU 2007 (MiB)
[MemUsageChange] Init cuDNN: CPU +1, GPU +10, now: CPU 1178, GPU 2017 (MiB)
[MemUsageChange] TensorRT-managed allocation in engine deserialization: CPU +0, GPU +158, now: CPU 0, GPU 158 (MiB)
[MemUsageChange] Init cuBLAS/cuBLASLt: CPU +1, GPU +8, now: CPU 1182, GPU 2021 (MiB)
[MemUsageChange] Init cuDNN: CPU +0, GPU +8, now: CPU 1182, GPU 2029 (MiB)
Segment fault

If anyone can help me, it will save my life.
I checked all the environments again and it worked perfectly with python, but there was a problem with C++
Debuger log:

Thread 1 "main" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffd7663328 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
ERROR: Couldn't get registers: no such process.
[Switching to thread 2 (Thread 0x7fffcdc77000 (LWP 97457))]
[Thread 0x7fffcc810000 (LWP 97463) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffcd476000 (LWP 97458) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffcdc77000 (LWP 97457) exited]

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

This happens when my program enter nvinfer1::IExecutionContext* context = engine->createExecutionContext()
    IExecutionContext* createExecutionContext() noexcept
    {
        return mImpl->createExecutionContext();
    }


Have you tried to catch the crash in a debugger, to see when and where in code it happens?

You never check that the file has opened successfully. If it does not you just end up with a null pointer for trtModelStream. I don't know anything about this API but that's my guess as to what is going wrong. Seems pretty likely to me.

Please provide a [mre].

I have Supplemented the information encountered by debug. I am a beginner in tensorRT and have no idea about the registers process.
